# Audio session enumerator doesn't list all sessions, when run as service

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I'm trying to get the volume info of active audio sessions under Windows, and send it to an external device. The code is working fine, when I run it from the command line. I wanted it to be run in the background, so I made it a windows service, but it doesn't list any running applications. I can only get info about the Master session, and the system sounds (PID 0).

Interestingly, when the service is running, the built in volume mixer shows 2 "System sounds" sliders.

When I run the service, and try to get the session info from the command line (exact same code), I can see 2 sessions with PID 0. It also lists all sessions, not like the service.

I tried to debug the code, and `IAudioSessionEnumerator::GetCount()` says only one session exists, which is the system sounds. There are 2 more active sessions, which are reported in the command line, and the build in volume mixer.

Below is a stripped version of the code. In "production", I check all return values, and nothing fails, when I debugged the code, only GetCount returned the wrong value.

```
CoCreateInstance(__uuidof(MMDeviceEnumerator), 
    NULL, CLSCTX_ALL, __uuidof(IMMDeviceEnumerator), (void**)&enumerator);

enumerator->GetDefaultAudioEndpoint(EDataFlow::eRender, ERole::eMultimedia, &device);
device->Activate(__uuidof(IAudioSessionManager2), CLSCTX_ALL, NULL, (void**)&manager);
manager->GetSessionEnumerator(&sessionEnumerator);
sessionEnumerator->GetCount(&sessionCount);
// session count is 1 at this point in service, and 3 in the command line

/*
loop sessions, get desired info about them, works correctly
*/
```

Comment: Create another user on the machine and switch to it while the original user is still logged in. Does the command line version display info for both login sessions?

Comment: @Anders No, it doesn't, neither does the Volume Mixer. And the audio stops playing after I switch to the other account. The service's username in task manager is SYSTEM. I set the service to log on as my User, but no change in behavior.

Comment: Some APIs are not supported when running as a service and/or in session 0. If it does not work when logged in as another user then the API is likely per session.

Comment: You will likely need to make the service launch a non-service process in each user session, and then those processes can query the audio sessions and send the details back to the main service as needed.

Comment: That's a shame. I think I'll look for other solutions, because launching a program under a user from a service seems a bit too hack-y